# Do member references pad out classes? Or are they simply larger than non-member references?

Tags: c++

I was playing with some reference to template base member code. Out of curiosity, I wondered if the compiler optimised out my references behind the scenes somehow (as the references were all to the same variables in the parent class every time). I decided a simple sizeof() test would tell me. To my great surprise, simply referencing the 3 float members of the class I was inheriting from, blew my class memory footprint up by 333%. This surprised and confused me greatly.

After some fiddling, I don't even know what is going on (but I suspect I'm being dumb).

Code: (compiled in Code::Blocks 13.12 using GCC 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class FooArray{
public:
    FooArray(){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            m_data[i] = static_cast<T>(0);
        }
    }
    FooArray(const T& _krv){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            m_data[i] = _krv;
        }
    }

    T& operator[](unsigned int _index);

private:
    T m_data[N];
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
T&
FooArray<T, N>::operator[](unsigned int _index)
{
    return m_data[_index];
}

class Inherit0Ref : public FooArray<float, 3>{};

class Inherit1Ref : public FooArray<float, 3>
{
public:
    Inherit1Ref():a((*this)[0]){}
    float& a;
};

class Inherit2Ref : public FooArray<float, 3>
{
public:
    Inherit2Ref():a((*this)[0]), b((*this)[1]){}
    float& a;
    float& b;
};

class Inherit3Ref : public FooArray<float, 3>
{
public:
    Inherit3Ref():a((*this)[0]), b((*this)[1]), c((*this)[2]){}
    float& a;
    float& b;
    float& c;
};

class Inherit2RefMul : public FooArray<float, 3>
{
public:
    Inherit2RefMul():a((*this)[0]), b((*this)[1]){}
    float& a, b;
};

class Inherit3RefMul : public FooArray<float, 3>
{
public:
    Inherit3RefMul():a((*this)[0]), b((*this)[1]), c((*this)[2]){}
    float& a, b, c;
};

class FloatRef
{
public:
    FloatRef(float& _r):a(_r){}

    float& a;
};

class WrapFloat
{
    float pad;
};

class PadFloatRef
{
public:
    PadFloatRef():a(pad), pad(0.0f){}

    float& a;
    float pad;
};

int main()
{
    Inherit3Ref test;
    test.a = 1.0f;
    test.b = 2.0f;
    test.c = 3.14f;

    std::cout << test[0] << ", " << test[1] << ", " << test[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "float size: " << sizeof(float) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "float& size: " << sizeof(float&) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FloatRef size: " << sizeof(FloatRef) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "WrapFloat size: " << sizeof(WrapFloat) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PadFloatRef size: " << sizeof(PadFloatRef) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FooArray<float, 3> size: " << sizeof(FooArray<float, 3>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Inherit0Ref size: " << sizeof(Inherit0Ref) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Inherit1Ref size: " << sizeof(Inherit1Ref) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Inherit2Ref size: " << sizeof(Inherit2Ref) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Inherit3Ref size: " << sizeof(Inherit3Ref) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Inherit2RefMul size: " << sizeof(Inherit2RefMul) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Inherit3RefMul size: " << sizeof(Inherit3RefMul) << std::endl;

    // Supposedly size 32, lets test assignment and access.
    Inherit3RefMul testvar;
    testvar.a = 5.0f;
    testvar.b = 4.0f;
    testvar.c = 3.142f;

    // Interesting...
    // testvar: 5, 0, 0
    std::cout << "testvar: " << testvar[0] << ", " << testvar[1] << ", " << testvar[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3.14
float size: 4
float& size: 4
FloatRef size: 8
WrapFloat size: 4
PadFloatRef size: 16
FooArray<float, 3> size: 12
Inherit0Ref size: 12
Inherit1Ref size: 24
Inherit2Ref size: 32
Inherit3Ref size: 40
Inherit2RefMul size: 32
Inherit3RefMul size: 32
testvar: 5, 0, 0
```

Very curious. :)
Why is a wrapped float reference(FloatRef) twice the size of a wrapped float(WrapFloat)?
Why does declaring 3 float references using one float reference keyword (Inherit3RefMul) yield the same footprint as the same class with 2 references rather than 3(Inherit2Ref)?
Why has only TestVar's first variable been populated while all 3 of test's are populated as expected?
Is there some way to achieve the functionality of Inherit3Ref without the ridiculous memory footprint of 40?

EDIT:

Please note:

`sizeof(float&) == 4`

Update:

Running `alignof(float&)` returns 4. I don't see the reason for a float[3] float&[3] class to have size 40 when all variables have size of 4 and align of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler must add padding to ensure that any member variables are appropriately aligned. `float` has size 4 and alignment 4, while references and pointers (to whatever) have typically size 8 (on 64bit machines) and alignment 8. Hence:

```
struct foo {
  float m_data[3];             // size 3*4=12   begin=0   end=12
  float&a;                     // size 8        begin=16  end=24   NOTE: 4 unused bytes
};
```

(Also note that

```
float&a,b;
```

is equivalent to

```
float&a;
float b;
```

but not to

```
typedef float&float_ref;
float_ref a,b;
```

this notation is hence best avoided for clarity)

Comment: Thank you for the reference declaration note, I did not realise the syntax worked this way. However, note that `sizeof(float&)` returns 4. Having just tested, `alignof(float&)` also returns 4. Is this simply another programming error on my part? It seems strange that wrapping a reference size 4 makes the class size 8, while wrapping a float size 4 leaves the class size 4.

Comment: `sizeof(float&)` won't give you the size of the reference, but the size of the object referred to. References are strange beasts and almost always decay to the type referred to. Try `sizeof(std::reference_wrapper<float>)` to get the actual size of a reference.

Comment: Wow that's a cool type... I love the standard library! Thank you very kindly for your help @Walter.

Answer (score 2):

A float is 4-bytes, a reference is 8-bytes. So an array of 3 floats will be 12-bytes. The only non-trivial bit is your `Inherit3Ref`, which will look like:

```
float[3];
*** padding to 8 byte boundary ***
float &[3];
```

Hence 12 bytes for the floats + 4 bytes additional padding + 24 bytes for the references to make 40. If you want to avoid the padding, you can make the class packed - which should get you down to 36 bytes.

Not sure why you call it "ridiculous" - it certainly has to be at least 36...

Comment: **You got that wrong**: the padding is not to a 16-byte boundary, but to a 8-byte boundary, since `alignof(float&)==8`. It just so happens that in this case, the 8-byte boundary is also a 16-byte boundary.

Comment: @Walter oops. typo? :)

Comment: It's worth noting that `sizeof(float&)` in his output is 4, indicating that it's a 32-bit machine, so references do not appear to be 8 bytes in OP's case.

Comment: Except that as cdhowie points out, my output shows `sizeof(float&)` returns 4. Just tested `alignof(float&)` it also returns 4. Why should the class pad to an 8 byte boundry when all variables are 4 bytes in both size and alignment?